# Compiler assumes child class is virtual before I define its functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

Here's an example program demonstrating an issue I have with a big program.

Basically, I have the declarations of a parent and child class in an `.h` file. Because the parent class `A` is virtual, the compiler assumes that the child `B` is also virtual, and won't let me define its function in the `.cpp` file. The error says:

> candidate is: virtual void B::print()

But I don't want it to be virtual.

example.h file:

```cpp
class A{   
public:
    int x;
    A();
    virtual void print();
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void print(){};
};
```

example.cpp file:

```cpp
#include "example.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

A::A(){ x = 10; }

B::print(){ cout << x << endl; }
```

main.cpp file:

```cpp
#include "example.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to solve this issue, while maintaining the 3 separate files?

Comment: `int x;` is `private`. `B` can't see it.

Comment: The problem remains even when I remove the curly braces and make x public. I should edit those in the question cause i overlooked them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a method has been explicitly marked as `virtual`, it is always virtual in derived classes, even if it is not explicitly marked as `virtual` in those classes. There is no way to change that.

The reason for your error is that you have 2 competing and incompatible definitions of `B::print()` - one inline in `example.h`, and one in `example.cpp`. You need to remove the inline definition from `example.h`:

```cpp
class B : public A {
public:
    void print(); // <-- no braces here!
};
```

Also, the definition in `example.cpp` is missing the return type:

```cpp
void B::print() { cout << x << endl; } // <-- add 'void' here!
```

Comment: I thought I only needed to write the return type in the declaration and not the definition, that's why it wasn't working. The braces was just an overlook. It works now, thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeT "*I thought I only needed to write the return type in the declaration and not the definition*" - no. Both declaration and definition must have matching return type, calling convention, and argument types.